# heroku deploy error with static root path django. static_root not set to file system path

Tags: python, django, heroku, collectstatic

my static files settings are improperly configured according to heroku when I attempt to deploy. I am without doubt this is false as I still lack understanding of the proper way to set up static files.

I have ran collect static on my machine and it did work. I will provide the information my ask is to help me clear this up. I am going to continue to research and hope to come with a solution.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#angular distro root
ANGULAR_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/dist')


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(ANGULAR_APP_DIR),

]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

these are my current root urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', serve, kwargs={'path': 'index.html'}),
    url(r'^(?!/?static/)(?!/?media/)(?P<path>.*\..*)$',RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/%(path)s', permanent=False)),
    url(r'api/',include(rootapi)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `STATIC_URL` to your `urlpatterns`.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # your url patterns
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I just uploaded my question with my root urls. Is your answer still valid in my given situation? I am about to try your answer

Comment: Yes. Still valid and try.

Comment: just tired it. I did git commit and all. pushed to heroku with the same error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Comment: do you have your `static` directory at the same level with `manage.py` ??

Comment: but wasn't that created when i ran collectstatic?

Comment: create a directory named `static` with the same level as `manage.py` and then `add`, `commit`, `push`.

Comment: and keep your `static` files in your `static` directory.

Comment: will do trying now

Comment: so i created the static folder, then i ran collect static. I also changed the static root from `staticfiles` to `static` to which collect static once finished created a static folder one level below my static folder. my `project_root` path is going one level below where it should. The code for `project_root` is:

Comment: `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167533/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-gigglesonmadision).